# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value django-registration

Tags: mysql, django, django-registration

I recently loaded all of the django-registration tables from sqlite into a mysql database. It works fine for logging in users, but now when I try to register a user I get this error:

```
Warning at /accounts/register/
Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

I tried using this line to make the id field auto increment but I'm still getting the error.

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY id INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I ended up deleting all of the dables and using `manage.py syncdb` to recreate them although that isn't really a solution.

Comment: do you already solve this problem?

Comment: I ended up deleting my database and creating a new one, so I unfortunately don't have any way to test your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have incorrect table structure. Try to:

1. Create test project and setup connection to test blank database.
2. Then try to do `manage.py syncdb` on test project.
3. Compare table `auth_user` structure between current and test project. For example compare create table script for both projects.